# How to become a krunker police officer?

Tags: krunker.io

In the game krunker.io , i was wondering how can you enroll to become a kpd officer and what are the requirements?

Answer (score 1):

From the Krunker wiki, "To apply to the K.P.D, press the police icon next to your username and fill out the form. You must be level 50 to send an application."

Comment: oh thanks !! it must take a while to get to that level though !

Comment: Yah, it does. This is probably to prevent random players that arent experienced do it.

Answer (score 1):

The minimum requirements to join KPD are:

- Account is at least **Level 50**
- Must have at least **20 helpful reports**
- Ability to **record 720p** stable framerate
- Access to **Windows** operating system

Once these requirements are met you can fill out the KPD application **[found here](https://forms.gle/ZHpmaTH167z9bCgS9)**. To increase your chances of becoming KPD, try re-submitting your application at a higher level or more helpful reports. Furthermore, having a good reputation in the community increases your chances by a lot. Streaming, creating content, being active in communities, etc are favorable qualities for candidates.

If you aren't accepted within 60 days you can submit a new application with updated material. These requirements may change overtime but you can refer to the application link for the most up to date information.